# CSS: slide button onclick and show content?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to slide a button using CSS and jQuery and show the contents based on the button clicked.

I don't know what this effect called so I cannot use its name.

Here is an example (very messy) that I came up so you can understand what I'm trying to do:

http://jsfiddle.net/Te9T5/2238/

If you click on the button 1 and button 2, you will see the slide animation.

This is my CSS:

```
.box img {
    -webkit-transition:1s;
}
.box img.clicked{
    margin-left:50px;
 }

 .b{
   position:absolute;
   left:25px;
 }
 .b:hover{
   curser:pointer;
 }

  .btn1{
   position:absolute;
   left:25px;

 }


  .btn2{
   position:absolute;
   left:100px;


 }

  .btn3{
   position:absolute;
   left:160px;

 }
```

And this is my jquery:

```
$('.b').on('click', function() {
    $('.box img').toggleClass('clicked');
});
```

**Questions:**

1. what is the name of this effect?
2. could someone please advise on how to achieve this effect properly?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

This is what I have done so far. I am still trying to figure out what this effect called and haven't been able to find anything related to this as of yet:

http://jsfiddle.net/Te9T5/2239/

it is not as messy as the first code but still doesn't work the way I need it to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are there any examples online you've seen that relate to what you're after? Are you after a toggle style switch that slides between on and off, or something that toggles between button 1 and button 2? And what's the role of 'button 3'?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the sliding animation by calculating the position of each link and creating an event listener to animate the background :

```
var width_spn = $('.b').width();
var width_btn = 100;

// Initialize position

$('.box img').css({
  width: width_btn,
  left: (width_spn / 2) - (width_btn / 2)
});

// Setup animation

$('.b').click(function() {

  var left = $(this).position().left + (width_spn / 2) - (width_btn / 2);

  $('.box img').stop().animate({
    'left': left
  });
});
```

Complete example based on your code :

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/r_costa/onk5gdut/)